# Bootstrap addons not working properly on different resolutions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

It looks like there is a bug in [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic). If you change resolution, for example with ctrl + (+/-) in your browser the addons are not properly adjusted. It looks like this:

[image]

Notice the wrong sizes of addons.

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: Nope: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-browser-zooming

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no simple way (and quite possibly no way *period*) to fix problems related to the type of zooming that you're referring to (as opposed to the viewport-width-based zooming that you get when using the pinch gesture on touch-based devices).
[Per Bootstrap's documentation:](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-browser-zooming)

> Page zooming inevitably presents rendering artifacts in some components, both in Bootstrap and the rest of the web. [... these issues] often have no direct solution other than hacky workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Zooming in and out is not changing the resolution at all its zooming and is completely different from changing the view port's aspect ratio and dimensions.

Give the input area a fixed width like `input {width:100px}`

Comment: The solution is to not zoom.